# Is there any way to search from the Project Explorer in Scala IDE or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

I've recently switched to Scala-IDE for Scala development, especially since they added Scala Worksheets - what a cool feature.

Anyways, my biggest gripe with Eclipse is searching for text. I was unable to find an add-on or mechanism that would allow me to search or search-and-replace text in from the project explorer.

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 and would like to be able to just right-click on a folder or package in the Project Explorer and select 'search', to search that folder and it's sub-folders.

Is there a plug-in available for that or am I missing the elephant in the room? I tried using the search menu option from the main application menu, but it does not seem to take context (like the current package) into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the search dialog of eclipse are several tabs. The **File Search** and the **Java Search** tabs have a box named **Scope**. It allows you to restrict your search to the **Selected resources**.

Answer (score 2):

In the search dialog you have the option as well of **enclosing projects** on the scope box, this will search only on the project you are working at that moment, without the need of selecting the project and then open the search dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The only way as far asI know is search with your keyword in the project and each open each file and do find and replace/replaceAll.

ScalaIDE is growing but it is still not that powerfull.